# With the GAE Bulk Uploader script, how do I deal with empty values in the CSV?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I've set up my app.yaml and data_uploader files as suggested in this document. My CSV file has some null values (the spreadsheet that I exported had some empty cells).

When I run the script, I get this error in the log file: 
**[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-0: Value should not be empty; received []**.

My guess is that it is because some values are empty in the csv file, How can I make sure that the empty values are either imported as '' into the datastore, or not imported at all (the model properties are all optional).

Thanks, David.

Comment: Take a look at this section of the docs : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader You can configure how data is imported in bulkloader.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should customize your `bulkloader.yaml` giving the right directive in the property map section.

Check if the `import_transform` element on your model kind property that gives problem is set, and try to use the `none_if_empty` directive .

```
- property: fooproperty
  external_name: fooproperty
  import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(foopropertytype)
```

This is what [none_if_empty](http://code.google.com/p/soc/source/browse/thirdparty/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py?r=a45db1c4cb30a0ecdacd3ee19432c7fa7232e21e) does:

```
def none_if_empty(fn):
  """A wrapper for a value to return None if it's empty. Useful on import.

  Can be used in config files (e.g. "transform.none_if_empty(int)" or
  as a decorator.

  Args:
    fn: Single argument transform function.

  Returns:
    Wrapped function.
  """

  def wrapper(value):
    if value == '' or value is None:
      return None
    return fn(value)

  return wrapper
```

Afaik, bulkloader generates the bulkloader.yaml file inferring the proper configuration using the production datastore stats; just check if the assumptions made are correct.